# How to arrange editTexts automatically on different screens?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I've created a RelativeLayout with lots of editTexts, and now I see that, if I change the screen, the editTexts aren't arranged anymore as I setted. I don't know what and how to set all to remain the same on all screens.

*I tried creating the layout-small, layout-large, etc, but it's not changing anything.

Here is my

**medii.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mediib"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText24"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText22"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText14"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText23"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText33"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText34"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText34"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText36"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText35"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText35"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText33"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText32"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText37"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText37"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText38"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText34"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText32"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText32"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText32"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText35"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText37"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText37"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText31"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText34"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText33"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText29"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText34"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText34"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText33"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText28"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText33"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText29"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText31"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText30"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText33"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText39"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText35"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText38"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/medie"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText38"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText29"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText29"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText35"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText24"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText38"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText29"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText27"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText35"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText38"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bmedii3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText39"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText39"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText19"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText19"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText26"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText18"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText18"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText18"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText26"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText26"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText26"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText24"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText14"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText13"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText34"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText12"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText16"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText15"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText15"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText16"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText16"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText8"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText10"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText17"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText6"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText32"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText37"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bmedii2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText23"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText29"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText23"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText28"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText22"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText28"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText28"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText29"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText30"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText22"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText19"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText33"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/teze"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText16"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText17"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText17"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/medie"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bmedii2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText20"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText20"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText20"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bmedii2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/medie"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText41"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bmedii"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText37"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText9"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText40"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText30"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText22"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText22"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:background="@drawable/nota2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/nota" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here are

Some pictures of how it looks:

**Normal:**

[image]

**Abnormal:**

[image]

Comment: you can use weight property of linearLayout to achieve this

Comment: offtopic: try to use styles when you have many equally styled elements. it makes xml smaller and more readable.

Comment: You may try LinearLayout...

Comment: check this link to see how to use layout_weight attribute on xml: http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

Comment: Not working with LinearLayout because it can't deal with the alignments I have..

Comment: Couldn't have it done in anyway. Does anyone have any other idea, please?